# Salto de línea automático TextBox WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

Necesito implementar un salto de línea automático en un `TextBox` en **`WPF`**.
Es decir, cuando la aplicación esté en ejecución y escriba sobre el `TextBox` dar un salto línea cuando se aproxime al final del `TextBox (Width)`, sin necesidad de dar **`ENTER`**. Grax !

Comment: No conozco mucho de WPF, pero seguro te sirve [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b8e8f9b-b8a6-4a2e-8c9e-4987f2e6ab44/how-to-detect-when-a-string-added-to-a-textbox-will-trigger-a-new-line-feed?forum=wpf). Saludos!

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

En XAML puedes crear un control Textbox multilínea añadiendo la propiedad `TextWrapping="Wrap"`.

Como se indica en [la documentación de WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-multiline-textbox-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

> Si se establece el atributo en Wrap, el texto especificado se ajustará a una nueva línea cuando se alcance el borde del control, expandiendo automáticamente el control para incluir espacio para una nueva línea, si es TextWrapping TextBox TextBox necesario.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> <TextBox
>  Name="tbMultiLine"
>  TextWrapping="Wrap"
>  AcceptsReturn="True"
>  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
> >
>  This TextBox will allow the user to enter multiple lines of text.  
>  When the RETURN key is pressed, or when typed text reaches the edge
>  of the text box, a new line is automatically inserted.
> </TextBox>
> ```